# Can't transfer files to/from Amazon EC2 free machine with FTPS

Tags: ftp, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, filezilla, ftps

I have a free amazon EC2 machine. for some reason I can not transfer files using FileZilla from the EC2 machine to my local machine. I entered the machine public DNS and user name (which is ubuntu as my machine is Ubuntu 18.04).

```
ftps://mymachine.compute.amazonaws.com
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

The keys are added to th FileZilla. I have tried file transfer in non-free machines and it was successful.

Is file transfer to/from free EC2 machines allowed? Can you suggest any solutions?

Comment: Did you install a FTP server (vsftpd for example)? 
Did you allow the ports (if using FTP port 20 and 21, and 22 if using SFTP) on your security group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no FTP server running in Linux machines (EC2 or other) by default.

You probably wanted to **use SFTP**, but mistaken it with FTPS (FTP over TLS/SSL).